# My while loop won't work

Tags: php

In this script, I basically want to echo out data from a mysql table when the certain row record matches the name in browser address bar. But for some reason, no data is echoed. Any reason my while loop doesn't work?

```
 $users = $_GET['username'];



$other_friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend WHERE RelatingUser='$users'");
$other_friend_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_friend_query);


while ($other_friend_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_friend_query)) {
    $friend_related = $other_friend_assoc['RelatedUser'];
      echo $friend_related;




  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Just to add to what @MadaraUchiha said - your current code isn't checking for any errors and has a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you call `mysql_fetch_assoc` before your `while` loop. When you call this, it fetches a result. Then when you go to your loop, that result has already been fetched. Just remove that and you'll be good to go. As stated in the comments, stop using `mysql_` functions. The code below will escape your posted variable and also check for errors. It's also better practice to use a column list, instead of `SELECT *`.

```
$users = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);

$other_friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend WHERE RelatingUser='$users'") or die( mysql_error() );

while( $other_friend_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_friend_query) ) {
    $friend_related = $other_friend_assoc['RelatedUser'];
    echo $friend_related;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any reason my while loop doesn't work?

May not be the *only reason*, but you're skipping the first result.

```
// the following line is unused and therefore unnecessary
$other_friend_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_friend_query);

while ($other_friend_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_friend_query)) {
```